# React-Native: Panresponder inside of a scrollview on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, scrollview

Essentially my issue is accurately presented and answered in this blog post from Oct 2015:

http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-pan-responder-inside-of-a-scrollview/

Since the time of writing, `scrollEnabled` has been implemented in Android, however it does not seem to be a solution that works in my use case. I have a ScrollView that contains elements which utilize a panresponder that relies on `scrollEnabled` to toggle the ScrollView's, well, scrolling feature.

My code works perfectly on iOS as described in the above blog post, but on Android the ScrollView does not take responding away from the children when `scrollEnabled` is set to true.

Struggling to find a workaround. Does anyone know how to properly do this? Or does the implementation of `scrollEnabled` on Android not support this panresponder handoff?

Comment: Hey Jason, did you ever come to a solution to this problem? I'm dealing with exactly the same thing, trying to get a sortable list view scrolling when you don't long press a row. Here's what I'm working on: https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list/issues/15

Comment: @JoshPinter unfortunately I can't remember the solution I found. Right now the "enableScroll" works for us, but only in a limited sense. I can dig more if you have more information about your usage concerns

Comment: FYI, for Android you need to set `onShouldBlockNativeResponder` to return `false` when you create your `PanResponder`. This ensures that the Native OS handles the scroll as expected. Then you can implement a long press or something to allow the `PanResponder` to take over the gestures. As per: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html#create

Comment: That is the answer ^